# Working with ActiveRecord::Relation objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, initialization

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to initilizate a new `ActiveRecord::Relation` so that I have the possibility to populate it myself with class objects (all objects of the same "type") using the `<<` method; otherwise (for my needs) I have to istantiate a new Ruby `array` class but using that array I can not run methods (example the `where`, `order`, etc...) as for an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

[Seeing the RoR code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb) I found this in the :

```
def initialize(klass, table)
  @klass, @table = klass, table

  @implicit_readonly = nil
  @loaded            = false

  SINGLE_VALUE_METHODS.each {|v| instance_variable_set(:"@#{v}_value", nil)}
  (ASSOCIATION_METHODS + MULTI_VALUE_METHODS).each {|v| instance_variable_set(:"@#{v}_values", [])}
  @extensions = []
end
```

but I have not found a good documentation about that.

**How can I initializate an `ActiveRecord::Relation`? Is it a common practice to work directly on "custom" `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects? What do you advice about?**

P.S.: Maybe I must use an AssociationCollection because, at the end of all operations with which I add (using `<<`) class objects, I need to use its related `replace` method.

Comment: Why don't you define a model for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your requirements. Overwriting initialize is unheard of for application requirements. The API is quite strong and there's usually no need to overwrite AREL methods.

Could you use something like `MyModel.scoped` to get the base relation? Are you looking for 2 collections (one from DB, and one pre-prepared)?

Based on the comment:
MyModel.scoped would give a base relation - you could do:

```
pre_prepared_items = [item1, item2, item3]
my_items = MyModel.where("x = z").order("a ASC")
@mixed_items = pre_prepared_items + my_items
```

or you could prepare 2 distinct collection and would be up to the view to display them accordingly.

```
@pre_prepared_items = [item1, item2, item3]
@my_items = MyModel.where("x = z").order("a ASC)
```

Comment: "Could you use something like MyModel.scoped to get the base relation?" Yes, I can if that scope accomplish at what I aim. - "Are you looking for 2 collections (one from DB, and one pre-prepared)?" - Yes, I am.